# Irreducibility of integer polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

$\newcommand{\rational}{\mathbb{Q}}$

I have met the following interesting problem:

> Prove, given a positive integer $n \geq 12$, if an integer polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n$ evaluates to $\pm 1$ at more than $[\frac{n}{2}] + 1$ distinct integers of $x$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\rational$. Can the lower bound $12$ of the degree $n$ be further reduced?

My attempt:
Assume the contrary, $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$, where $\deg(g(x)) < n, \deg(h(x)) < n$. Denote $[n/2] + 1$ by $m$, then either $\deg(g(x)) < m$ or $\deg(h(x)) < m$, say $g(x)$. Let $a_1, \ldots, a_m$ be $m$ distinct integers such that $f(a_i) = \pm 1, i = 1, \ldots, m$. Then $g(a_i) = \pm 1, i = 1, \ldots, m$. As $\deg(g(x)) < m$, this implies that there exists $1 \leq j < m$, such that $g(a_1) = \cdots = g(a_j) = 1$ while $g(a_{j + 1}) = \cdots = g(a_m) = -1$. Since $g$ is an integer polynomial and $a_1, \ldots, a_m$ are distinct, this requires $j \leq 3$ and $m - j \leq 3$, whence $m \leq 3 + j \leq 6$. Therefore $n \leq 11$. This contradicts with $n \geq 12$.

How about the second part of the problem? Does there exist an integer polynomial of degree less than $12$ with the stated property? I have difficulty to construct one.

Comment: How about $f(x)=(x^2-x-1)^2$? We have $n=\deg f=4$ and $f(-1)=f(0)=f(1)=f(2)=1$ and so we have $4$ distinct integers giving $f(x)=1$ with $4 > [\frac{4}{2}] + 1=3$.

Comment: @Sil Thanks. So can we prove that if $n \geq 5$, then $f(x)$ with the stated property is irreducible? Otherwise we may need to find out a polynomial with degree at least $11$?

Comment: That's true, it might be worth trying to find larger counterexample first. For proof, the assumption on the coefficients being integers is important (for rational coefficients it is easy to find counterexample as my now deleted answer shows).

Comment: For that matter, for $n=5$ we can use $f(x)=(x^2+x-1)(x^3+2x^2-x-1)$.

Comment: @Sil I can slightly reduced $n$ from $12$ to $10$ (with some obvious modification in my proof above). On the other hand, it looks difficult to construct an order $9$ polynomial such that it takes $+1$ for $3$ times and takes $-1$ for $3$ times (which corresponds to the only possibility that $f$ is reducible).

Comment: You can't have integer polynomial that attains $-1$ three times at $x_1<x_2<x_3$ as well $+1$ three times at $x_4<x_5<x_6$, because then we can show that there are at least $5$ distinct values of differences $x_i-x_j | f(x_i)-f(x_j)=2$ (standard divisibility property of integer polynomials $a-b \mid P(a)-P(b)$). However $2$ have only $4$ distinct integer divisors $\pm 1, \pm 2$, contradiction. Those $5$ distinct values can be picked up as $x_1-x_6<x_1-x_5<x_1-x_4<x_2-x_4<x_3-x_4$.

Comment: You are right. I think the question should be modified a little bit from "at more than" to "at", in which case I think I can prove that the lowest bound for irreducibility is $8$, and for $n = 7$, $f(x) = (x(x - 1)(x - 3) + 1)(x(x - 1)(x - 2)(x - 3) + 1)$ can be used as a counterexample.